# Excel;seek medianvalue with if statement over a range of values

Tags: excel, if-statement, range, median

I seek the median value for a group of ages: `18-24, 25-29, 30-34` and so on. I have the data in sheeet Wages; wages in column `G` and ages in column `I`.

In the output sheet I have formed a range of ages in `B9:B58` from 18 years in `B9` to 67 years in `B58` to "help" to form the formula. I tried this for 18-24 years (7 years interval in B9:B15):

```
=MEDIAN(IF((Wages!$I$1:$I$7000=B9:B15),Wages!$G$1:$G$7000)).
```

(The rest should be in 5 years interval)

Comment: Please put some effort into formatting your question. As it is, it is very difficult to read. I gave up halfway through.

Comment: Ok. How do I get a medianvalue with a range of conditional values with help of an IF statement?I  tried this: =MEDIAN(IF((Wages!$I$1:$I$7000=B9:B58),Wages!$G$1:$G$7000)).

Comment: ^^^ doesn't count as "effort".

Comment: What is it that you dont get?

Comment: So you want the median for each range apart? Would be useful to add an example with data.

Comment: Yes I want the medianvalues for 18-24 years ( 7 years interval) and then for 25-29 years and so on (5 years interval). So I tried the formula for 18-24 years: =MEDIAN(IF((Wages!$I$1:$I$7000=B9:B15),Wages!$G$1:$G$7000)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write or generate in columns `A` and `B` the bounds of your ranges, so that `A9:B9 = 18, 24`, `A10:B10 = 25, 29` etc... until `A18:B18 = 65, 69`. Then write this **Array Formula** (paste then click Ctrl+Shift+Enter) in `C9` :

```
=MEDIAN(IF((Wages!$I$1:$I$7000>=$A9)*(Wages!$I$1:$I$7000<=$B9), Wages!$I$1:$I$7000))
```

Then you can copy/paste `C9` into `C10:C18`.